# PERL Tk and Forks Mismatch Modules

Tags: perl

I'm developing a Perl multi-threading software for Windows and Linux, by using threads and forks modules respectively.
Everything works fine with standard output directed to shell, however once i decide to produce a GUI by including Tk module into the script, just the Windows version of the app works fine (actually not really well, but the output is acceptable), as when i try to run it on Linux together with Forks module and a simple button starting the script, something went wrong.

Below, you can find the error message associated with it:

```
***.button (1):
 0 0x32bef88   IV f=00000001 undef(1)
SV = IV(0x32bef78) at 0x32bef88
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = ()
  IV = 0
Prototype mismatch: sub CORE::GLOBAL::exit (;$) vs none at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.0/x86_64-linux/forks.pm line 1509.***
```

The prototype mismatch could be linked with a common function embedded into both Tk and Forks modules, but honestly i don't know how to solve it.
I've been trying to include specific 'forks' of 'Tk' functions, but no way to fix it.

Thanks in advance for any help on this subject.

Comment: Please provide a (minimal) example code that shows how you load `Tk` and `forks` modules, and how you you fork a process

Comment: Perl/TK is not thread safe as far as I know, i.e. all Tk related things have to be done always from inside the same thread. But fork in Windows is emulated using threads.

Comment: Also, "Using exit from a forked process will terminate both the child process and the parent process. As Tk::exit is imported by default one should use CORE::exit in the forked process instead."

Comment: Thanks. I seem to understand there's a conflict between same fuctions defined into both thee aforementioned modules. Isn't there a way to remove (not importing) CORE::exit function from Tk or even Forks when declaring them at the beginning of the script?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in the `forks` module. Not a terribly serious one, but the issue lies with the `forks` module.

The perl builtin `exit` function should have a prototype

```
$ perl -E 'say prototype "CORE::exit"'
;$
```

The `forks` module [sometimes tries to redefine the `exit` function](https://metacpan.org/source/RYBSKEJ/forks-0.36/lib/forks.pm#L551)

```
{
    no warnings 'redefine';
    *CORE::GLOBAL::exit = $old_core_global_exit;
}
```

but it does so with [a subroutine that was not defined with a prototype](https://metacpan.org/source/RYBSKEJ/forks-0.36/lib/forks.pm#L496)

```
# Keep reference to pre-existing exit function
my $old_core_global_exit;
BEGIN {
    $old_core_global_exit = sub { CORE::exit(@_) };
}
```

Again, this is not a serious bug, but if you want to fix it, edit your copy of `forks.pm` to include a prototype in the sub definition

```
    $old_core_global_exit = sub (;$) { CORE::exit(@_) };
```

and if you want a permanent fix, [contact the author](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RYBSKEJ/forks-0.36/lib/forks.pm#CURRENT-AUTHOR-AND-MAINTAINER) and make a bug report.

Comment: Thanks mob. I just replaced the *CORE::GLOBAL::exit = $old_core_global_exit; line with the new one: $old_core_global_exit = sub (;$) { CORE::exit(@_) }; within the sub BEGIN. Unfortunately it doesn't work...the output it still the same. Reported bug seems the same as the Tk module one, included into the script. Any idea?